# How to subtract the same amounts to all values in a column?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I was wondering if I can subtract the same value (offset) to all values of a specific column in my table.

For example I have:

```
Col1
------
34
35
36
```

I want to make it:

```
Col1
------
24
25
26
```

What's the SQL code for doing it ?

Comment: it wasn't clear whether this was for display/resultset or whether you wanted to save those values back to the table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you just doing this for display, or do you want to update the table with the reduced values?

In the first case:

```
select (Col1 - 10) from table
```

In the second (assuming you want to update ALL rows):

```
update table set Col1 = (Col1 - 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
 SELECT (MyCol - 10)
 From MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks Ponies. That's twice now, but you've beaten me a handful of times ;)

Comment: But slower than me, and with less content.

In fact, UPDATE p.campbell SET posttime = djacobson's post time + 10

;)

Comment: You forgot the WHERE clause.  Now all hell will break lose.